# close ssh connection with keygen

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I've established a port forwarding using an ssh connection to my remote server using keygen as codes below :

`ssh-keygen -t rsa` and `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@IP`

`ssh -N -R 0.0.0.0:53407:localhost:53407 root@IP`

Now i need to end this but still my port 53407 is using by ssh , how can i end this connection?

[return of lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG1Ax.png)

Ive deleted the port forwarding service yet nothing changed

Comment: (1) "Ive deleted the port forwarding service" -- What exactly do you mean? (2) When asking about SSH, in general it's good to explicitly state for each command if it was invoked client-side or server-side. Your question fails to do this. I especially mean `lsof` that looks like it has been invoked on the server, but we cannot be sure until you tell us. (3) To terminate port forwarding set up by `ssh -N ...` usually you just need to kill the `ssh` process. Did you do that? Is the issue because `sshd` did not notice?

Comment: (4) [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618). Improve the question by [edit]ing it. Add information there, not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

- In the "dead" terminal, where you started the `ssh -N ...` you can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to cancel the `ssh` process.
- If you sent it to the background get the job back to the foreground to send it a `^C`.

```sh
# At the client system:

# To find it:
jobs
[1]+  Running                 ssh -N -R53407:localhost:53407 user@server &

# To bring to foreground:
fg 1

# To cancel:
^c
```

- Else find the ssh process in your task list, get its process-id (PID) and execute:

```
kill <PID>
```

Using `kill` like this is not *an assassin at work* but more like a nice postman that hands out the message to `ssh` to *quit itself properly*. — So give ssh some seconds to do the quit-job.

---

Preferably you should check the open ports by `ss`:

```sh
# At the remote system:
sudo ss -tanp | grep "sshd"
```

---

This will also help, when you are local at the server to terminate the ssh connection:

```sh
# Alternatively at the server:
sudo ss -tanp | grep ":53407"

LISTEN  0       128                 127.0.0.1:53407     0.0.0.0:*       users:(("sshd",pid=247750,fd=9))                                               
LISTEN  0       128                     [::1]:53407        [::]:*       users:(("sshd",pid=247750,fd=8))                                               

# Get the PID from the output and send the kill command:
kill 247750
```

*Note: Other sshd connections will not quit, as `sshd` forks for each connection, so using a different PID for each of them.*